# Our 13-year-old dog constantly chews the bottom of her paw or sucks on blankets

Tags: dogs

Our 13-year-old dog constantly chews the bottom of her paw or sucks on blankets and articles of clothing. How can we stop this behavior? Is it dangerous to her health?

Comment: Can you provide some more information such as breed, more information about the behaviour and any patterns you've noticed, please? This will help us to answer your question. You may wish to read [ask].

Comment: Have you inspected her paws to make sure she doesn't have a bur or pebble between the pads, or a cut of some sort? Also, are you in a winter climate where she would have been walking on salted sidewalks/roads? And, is she acually sucking on the fabric, or is she laying on them and slobbering or chewing on toys near them?